# Swift - password protected view controller

Tags: ios, swift, passwords, segue

I'm trying to make a password protected view controller.

so far -

Created storyboard - 
on viewcontroller - created hard coded log in -
prints to console if successful or not.

textfields etc...

```
@IBOutlet weak var untext: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var pwtext: UITextField!


let username = "admin"
let password = "adminpw"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pwtext.isSecureTextEntry = true
}

@IBAction func loginbtn(_ sender: Any) {
    if untext.text == username && pwtext.text == password
    {
        print("log in succesful")
    }   else {
        print("log in failed")
    }

}
```

The issue I have, once I press the login button, it takes me to the admin page if successful or not.

How can I print a notification - on screen - if unsuccessful and remain on the current view controller, and if successful, take me to admin view controller?

Comment: Welcome, but Help us help you by posting the full code you've tried relating to this issue on the view controller, where's  `untext ` and `pwtext `?

Comment: added more code as requested

Comment: ok if the login in successful, perform a segue to say the `AdminViewController` else display do nothing but make an alert on the current view contrroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a segue or instantiateViewController. But in this example I'll use instantiateViewController (Images). (But commented how to use a segue)

1. Add a class and an identifier to your secondary ViewController
2. Choose between my Segue or Instantiate. (Check my comments in the code)
3. If login is succeeded, either perform the segue or navigate using instantiate.
4. Happy coding. :D

But first off, let's take a look at the code you provided.

```
@IBAction func loginbtn(_ sender: Any) 
{
     if untext.text == username && pwtext.text == password
     {
         print("login succeeded")
         //1. using instantiateViewController
         if let storyboard = storyboard
         {
             //Check my image below how to set Identifier etc.
             // withIdentifier = Storyboard ID & "ViewController" = Class 
             let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
             self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
         }
         //2. Use segue (I'll wrap this with a comment incase you copy)
         //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueID", sender: self)
     }
     else
     {
         //Setting up an "AlertController"
         let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Login failed", message: "Wrong username / password", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
         //Adding a button to close the alert with title "Try again"
         alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try again", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
         //Presentating the Alert
         self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
}
```

Click on the yellow dot on your ViewController (On the ViewController where you want the login-page to take you)

[image: image 1]

Click on the icon like I've. (Which is blue) and set a Class + Storyboard ID.

[image: image 2]

> NOTE! IF you wanna use a segue, make SURE you have a connection between ViewController(Login) and ViewController1

Comment: Thankyou! I used the segue method - as to be consistent with the app.  This worked exactly how i wanted it. I did have a small issue where the target viewcontroller was loading twice? i resolved this by changing the segue kind from show to present modally.

thanks again.

Comment: @Shane What I have heard, you should use "present modally" when creating login form. (Don't really ask me why) But the way I prefer is the instantiateViewController way. I've never got a single problem doing that way. :) Here is an article about why to not use segue:

https://medium.com/@leandromperez/avoiding-segue-identifiers-in-storyboards-2f582f85b3c1

I'm glad it worked out for you. :) Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use segues for navigation, you can put a "general purpose" segue (drag from your controller, instead of any controls in it) and assign it an ID (Identifier in attribute inspector of the segue in Storyboard). After that you can conditionally invoke segue from the parent controller class with your code:

```
if passwordCorrect {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueID", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help The Dreams Wind, i have added an identifier to the segue as stated, with the code you provided, how do i integrate this into my parent controller?